# Many categories in predicted variable with caret::knn3() gives column names of backend array error

Tags: r, prediction, r-caret, knn, categorical-data

I am using R, and I have an occupations variable with hundreds of categories, in a socioeconomic dataset. I want to classify and impute a selection of the observations, and I think knn is a suitable function which will handle the large number of categories. Below I outline my method using `caret`. I am trying to get past the error

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
> length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

When I use a binary variable (public employment) as the predicted variable, I do not come across the error in my MWE, so it appears that a large number of categories in the predicted variable causes a problem. Below I outline an MWE (without a seed) that creates the error **on some runs, but sometimes the error does not crop up**, depending on the randomization of `createDataPartition`.

Can you please tell me why the column names on some array in the backend matters, and also how the error gets created? I have kept an eye on the count of unique categories between `train_set_occupmerge` and `test_set_occupmerge` as I suspected that may play with the "array" dimension. However, logically it shouldn't matter if there are additional categories (against which accuracy is measured) in the test set as opposed to the training set, right?

```
# MWE

library(tidyverse)
library(caret)


df <- data.frame(
  age=c(
    1.633, -0.786, -1.132,  2.152, -0.614,  0.078, -0.009, -0.441, -0.354, -0.181, -0.527,  1.461, -0.441, -0.181, -1.478,  1.028, -1.391, -0.009,  0.078,  1.115
  ),
  realearnings = c(
    -0.314, -0.314, -0.458, -0.098, -0.458, -0.767, -0.623, -0.047, -0.252,  1.290, -0.458,  0.000,  0.000, 0.000, -0.616,  3.826, -0.664,  0.000,  0.000, -0.047
  ),
  occupmerge = c(
    1232, 1232, 4121, 4141, 4141, 7224, 9132,
    5162,
    1232, 1232, 4121, 4121, 7224, 7224, 7224, 1232, 7224, 1232, 1232, 4121
  )
)

length(unique(df$occupmerge))

train_index <- createDataPartition(
    df$occupmerge, 
    times=1, 
    p=0.5,
    list=FALSE
)
train_set <- df[as.numeric(train_index), ]
train_set_occupmerge <- factor(df %>% pull(occupmerge))[as.numeric(train_index)]

test_set <- df[-as.numeric(train_index), ]
test_set_occupmerge <- factor(df %>% pull(occupmerge))[-as.numeric(train_index)]

nrow(df)
nrow(train_set) + nrow(test_set)

length(unique(train_set_occupmerge))
length(unique(test_set_occupmerge))


knn_allvars <- knn3(x=train_set %>% select(-occupmerge), y=train_set_occupmerge, k=1)

knn_allvars_predict_test <- predict(knn_allvars, test_set %>% select(-occupmerge), type="class")

tab <- table(knn_allvars_predict_test, test_set_occupmerge)

accuracy <- function(x){sum(diag(x)/(sum(rowSums(x))))}
accuracy(tab)
```